# SQL JOIN self table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
col_1        col_2        col_3
10001        apple        3
10001        orange       2
10001        orange       5
10001        orange       8
```

How can I construct a SQL statement to get something like this:

```
col_1        col_2        col_3        col_2        col_3
10001        apple        3            orange       2
10001        apple        3            orange       5
10001        apple        3            orange       8
```

Comment: 1. Are there always 2 rows with the same `col_1` value? 2. Why `apple, 3` is to the left of `orange, 2` and not the other way round?

Comment: 1. nope, maybe more
2. yup, need to always like that

Comment: After the edit: 1. What if there were 2 `apple` rows and 3 `orange` ones? What should the result be then? All combinations of `apple` rows with `orange` rows, perhaps? 2. How do you decide which fruit goes first (to the left) and which second? Based on alphabetic order?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1 
    JOIN table t2 
        ON t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
        AND t1.col_2 < t2.col_2
```

Comment: is there a reason for the t1.col_2 < t2.col_2 statement?

Comment: without it, you'll return x^2 rows, where x is the number of items matching col_1. so in the sample data w/ apples/oranges, it'd return 4 rows (it'll match apples to apples, apples to oranges, oranges to apples, and oranges to oranges). presumably, we want only unique combinations of different col_2s, so the additional and col_2 < col_2 serves that purpose

Comment: I see, didn't notice that at first.

Comment: thanks alot.

i edit my question, this is what exactly i want

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.col_1=t2.col_1;`